# After running bs-cycle-next, the changed value of bs-current-configuration goes back to being files

Tags: buffers

The default value of `bs-current-configuration` is `"files"`. That being one of the elements in `bs-configurations`. I have the following configuration(s) in `debug.el` and run `emacs -Q -l debug.el`:

```lisp
(global-set-key [backtab] #'bs-cycle-next)
(use-package bs
  :config
    (defun buffer-sort-key (a  b)
      (string< (buffer-name a) (buffer-name b)))
    (add-to-list 'bs-configurations '(
        "my-config"; name
        nil; bs-must-show-regexp
        nil; bs-must-show-function
        nil; bs-dont-show-regexp
        nil; bs-dont-show-function
        buffer-sort-key)); bs-buffer-sort-function
    (setq bs-current-configuration "my-config"))
```

Right after launch, I check `C-h v bs-current-configuration` and indeed it is `"my-config"`. Then I run backtab, i. e., `bs-cycle-next` and again check `C-h v bs-current-configuration` to see that it has reverted to `"files"` again. Is this a bug?